# Using SWITCH to call different intents depending on what button was pressed

Tags: java, android

I cant seem to find any info on this anywhere.

Is it possible first?

Classic page with 5 buttons each open new page.

I guess the question is how do i create a listener for an unknown button?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by an "unknown" button, but yes, this is possible. Have your class implement onClickListener, and then in the onClick method, switch on v.getId():

```
public class IntentClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, OtherClass.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        //other cases here
        }
    }
}
```